# Why am I causing a Clustered Index Update?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm executing the following statement:

```
UPDATE TOP(1) dbo.userAccountInfo
SET           Flags = Flags | @AddValue
WHERE         ID = @ID;
```

The column 'ID' is an INT PRIMARY KEY with IDENTITY constraints.
Flags is a BIGINT NOT NULL.

The execution path indicates that a Clustered Index Update is occurring.  A very expensive operation.
There's no indexes covering Flags or ID, except for the primary key.
I feel like the actual execution path should be:

Clustered Index Seek => Update

Comment: You're definitely sure that the index is neither clustering nor covering the field [Flags]?

Comment: What's with the TOP(1) in the query?

Comment: @ Unknown Google:
I only have one nonclustered idx on this table.  It affects neither ID nor Flags.

@ BradC:
It's a bit of verbosity in my statement.  "This statement will affect exactly one user." But really serves no purpose.

Comment: Your verbosity adds one extra operator to the query plan. Likely the optimizer will drop it, as the primary key constraint ensures uniqueness, but you should just get rid of it nonetheless.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Tables come in two flavors: clustered indexes and heaps. You have a PRIMARY KEY constraint so you have created implicitly a clustered index. You'd have to go to extra length during the table create for this *not* to happen. Any update of the 'table' is an update of the clustered index, since the clustered index **is** the table.
As for the clustered index update being a 'very expensive operation', now that is an urban legend surrounding basic misinformation about how a database works. The correct statement is 'a clustered index update that affects the clustered key has to update the all non-clustered indexes'.

Comment: It's really a shame that there's so many... urban legends, as you put it... surrounding RDBs.  I've squashed a handful of them in the few weeks I've been writing SQL.  May I safely assume that, so long as I don't update ID, I wont cause a (potentially) grossly expensive operation to occur on the clustered data?

Comment: Updating ID would require a an update in *all* other indexes. Updating any other column that is part of an index would require an update of those indexes. A column that is not part of any index (as key or as contained column) would not cause any extra update. 
E.g. if you have an index on Flags then your update occur an extra update to maintain that index too. I wouldn't worry much about updates unless I evidence point to one being bad. Most often the unoptimized reads (scans) are the problem. BTW, what is the TOP (1) for? ID is PK, isn't it?

Answer (score 13):

The clustered index *is* the physical table, so whenever you update *any* row, you're updating the clustered index.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177434(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: I feel like I should only be doing a Clustered Index Update if I affect the primary key.
But I catch your point.
I guess I've sort of been brainwashed in to thinking clustered index updates are a hazardous thing.

Comment: Any way to avoid that?